# Is there a way to add a submodule to a git repo that share a directory structure

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a repo with a directory structure like so

    `/foo
    /foo/bar
    /foo/bar/me
    /foo/bar/you
    /foo/one
    /foo/one/two
    /foo/one/three`

There is a submodule I want to add that has this structure

    `/foo/bar/file.txt
    /foo/one/otherfile.txt`

Is there way to add that submodule to my repo, where the submodule shares some of the same directory structure?
I've tried using the basic add submodule commands, but I get the error that `'foo' already exists in the index`, which I take to mean that becuase my repo already has a /foo directory, it can't add the submodule with the same directory.

Is there anyway to have the submodule share the directory structure, but still have different files?

Comment: you might include the commands you've tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the submodule into a subfolder, for example `/foo/submodule`, so it looks like this:

```
/foo/submodule/foo/bar/file.text
/foo/submodule/foo/one/otherfile.txt
```

Then simply link the files in your repo:

```
/foo/bar/file.txt --> link to ../submodule/foo/bar/file.txt
/foo/one/otherfile.txt --> link to ../submodule/foo/one/otherfile.txt
```

This could even be expanded to automatically update the links and remove dead links when you update the submodule by a git hook if necessary.